# Read blob as data url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard, data-uri

I'm making a paste image from clipboard function
then I need to convert blob data to base64 encoded data url,
here's the code:

```
function handlepaste (event, e) { 
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    event.innerHTML = items[0].getAsFile();
    FileReader.readAsDataURL( event.innerHTML );

   if (event.childNodes && event.childNodes.length > 0) {
   $('body').append( event.innerHTML );
   }
    if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but the code's not working for me, Chrome console log says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function FileReader() { [native code] } has no method 'readAsDataURL'

How can I turn `[object Blob]` to `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850970/javascript-blob-object-to-base64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you haven't instantiated FileReader properly: `var file_reader = new FileReader();`

And then use `file_reader.readAsDataURL(...)`