# Using base64 in form to upload as file

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I have this simple upload form to browse and upload an image.

```
<form action="https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME" 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="key" type="text" value="objectName.txt" /><br/>
  <input name="file" type="file" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

But I'm using an image cropper, that outputs a `base64` string and want to upload that instead.

Now the browser doesn't allow me to set the value of the file input to the string, it wants a file.

Now I replaced:

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

With:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file" />
```

And handle the browsing/picking an image elsewhere.

Now this somehow **does** upload a file, but the image is invalid, it's just a text-file with the `base64` string inside it. Changing the type to `file` will fail the upload.

So I'm guessing it has to do with the `base64` having to be converted to a readable file.

After searching for converting base64 to file, I've tried:

```
blobData = atob(imageData)
```

But it errors: `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`, while if I paste the string (`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtW....etc`) into the address-bar it displays correctly. 
Same when I try this: http://wiki.lenux.org/base64-string-to-blob-object/
I there's a lot of different ways to convert it, but I keep getting the error on `atob` that it's not correctly encoded.

I feel there must be a simple solution, because the browser already knows how to decode the string.

I've found: http://www.nixtu.info/2013/06/how-to-upload-canvas-data-to-server.html that outputs only the size and type of the image, but does not convert it. And setting it as the value directly will result in a string: '[object Blob]`

Going deeper down the rabbithole: [Convert Blob to binary string synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208407/convert-blob-to-binary-string-synchronously) this converts the `blob` to a `Uint8Array`, I think I'm very close, but I'm lost right now.

To be clear, I'm looking for a client-side solution, and don't want to use `canvas` or any other extra helper elements.

Comment: Are you trying to upload `data URI` to server, or convert `data URI` to a `File` object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: @guest271314, convert it, uploading works, but now the file is a text-file with the raw data in it.

Comment: It is not possible to set a `File` object as a value of `FileList` object at `input type="file"` element. You can use AJAX to upload `FormData` object or `data URI` representation of file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the URI scheme instead of the data. You will have to get at the encoded data of the URI to decode it.

> ## data URI syntax
>
> Let's take a look again at this img tag and its
>   slightly disturbing syntax:
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..." />
> ```
>
> You have:
>
> - `data` - name of the scheme
> - `image/png` - content type
> - `base64` - the type of encoding used to encode the data
> - `iVBOR...` - the encoded data
> - some , and ; and : sprinked for good measure

http://www.phpied.com/data-urls-what-are-they-and-how-to-use/

The easiest way would be to split on the comma.

```
var image ="data:image/png;base64,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"
var decoded = atob(image.split(",")[1])
```

Comment: That worked, and now I have something like: PNG
then a lot of empty spaces, and then a lot of characters I can't seem to paste here, but it still won't load, and says it's an invalid image.

Comment: I think I maybe should not put the decoded string as text inside the `input` as `value`? But I don't know any other way to get this form to upload it.

Comment: When I compare the converted binary/hex it has a very different structure than a working image...

Comment: So when using this: http://decodebase64.com/ to decode a `base64` and just plain copy paste that into the file, it won't display. I am missing something essential here, but I have no idea where to look...

Comment: I guess you kindof answered half of the question, at least now I can convert it. But I still can't use that to generate a file. So, I've made a more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599064/convert-base64-to-file-to-upload-in-forminput-name-file