# Convert base64 to file to upload in <form><input name='file'/>

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I'm decoding a base64 to binary

```
var image ="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..."
var decoded = atob(image.split(",")[1])
```

Then want to upload it via a form:

```
<form action="https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME" 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="key" type="text" value="objectName.txt" /><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

I set the value of `input` with `name="file"` to the `decoded` string, but it will result in an `invalid image`.

I tried converting it to a `blob`, but when I set that as the value it results in `[Object blob]`

What am I missing here?

When I use: http://decodebase64.com/ and input the `base64` string, it outputs the same data, but `copy/pasting` that into a file, does not work apparently.

I'm surely missing an essential step between decoding the data, and making it into a working file...

- Do I have to encode the string and how?
- How do I find out what it should be encoded to?

(I'm browsing the file first, separately from the form. And then I crop it with some library, which spits out a working `base64` string. Now I just need the `form` to work with me and put this decoded data inside it. But like I mentioned, copy/pasting manually also doesn't work, so there is a step missing...)

Comment: Try using ajax to upload the data as a blob

Comment: @Musa, the server doesn't accept blobs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the very same thing and it turns out you can not manually set the file to upload in a form. It seems like a browser security thing. 
My workaround is to include a second hidden input field of type 'text' then pump the Base64 text into it. 
Then server side check if either is set.
Note: Now I continue my search on how to get the Base64 out of the input 'file' ;)