# How to use Resmush.it API from Apps Script (multi files upload)

Tags: google-apps-script, multipartform-data, urlfetch

I'm trying to use the resmush.it API from Apps Script and I'm struggling when making the request with `UrlFetch`.

From their [documentation](https://resmush.it/api), I understand they need a files array, in a multipart/form-data request.

What I'm doing so far (the images come from a Google Slides)

```
function myFunction() {
  const OPTIMIZER_URL = "http://api.resmush.it/ws.php"
  let slides = SlidesApp.openById("1TUZSgG_XXX_ni6VhdbE5usRyMc");
  let pages = slides.getSlides();
  pages.forEach((page) => {
    let images = page.getImages();
    images.forEach(image => {
        let payload = {
          files: [{
            file: image.getBlob()
          }]
        }
        let options = {
          method: "POST",
          payload: payload,
          muteHttpExceptions : true
        }
        let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(OPTIMIZER_URL, options)
        let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    })
  })
}
```

I also tried with `payload = { file: image.getBlob() }` but no success.

I get this error everytime:

```
{ error: 400,
  error_long: 'No file or url provided',
  generator: 'reSmush.it rev.3.0.4.20210124' }
```

Can you see what is wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: According to the documentation the files should be binary files rather than blob. Here is a question about how to convert a blob into a binary https://stackoverflow.com/q/27208407/1595451. If you need further help, please show what you tried to do the conversion and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: By guessing the specification of the API you want to use, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood the specification of the API, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether from your provided document I could correctly understand the specification of the API you want to use, how about the following modified script?

When I saw your script, I'm worried that your `image.getBlob()` has no name. In that case, the data is not sent as files. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. When my this guess is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const OPTIMIZER_URL = "http://api.resmush.it/ws.php"
  let slides = SlidesApp.openById("1TUZSgG_XXX_ni6VhdbE5usRyMc");
  let pages = slides.getSlides();
  pages.forEach((page) => {
    let images = page.getImages();
    images.forEach(image => {
      let options = {
        method: "POST",
        payload: { files: image.getBlob().setName("sample") },
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      }
      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(OPTIMIZER_URL, options)
      console.log(response.getContentText());
    })
  })
}
```

- In this modification, the request body uses `{ files: image.getBlob().setName("sample") }`. I'm not sure about the detailed specification of the API you want to use. So, if the key of `files` cannot be used, please modify `files` to `file` and test it again.
- And, if your API is required to use the unique names of the uploaded files for each request, please set the unique names by modifying `sample` of `image.getBlob().setName("sample")`.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I had to add the png extension in the `setName` function otherwise the API rejected it, but your solution worked!

Comment: @ValLeNain Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.