# How to paste image in chrome, then upload it to a server with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

I actually want to upload an image to a server.
To achieve this, i want the user just paste the image into chrome (the image is a print screen in fact), and then i post the stream to a php page, convert the stream as an image, and then upload it.

How can i achieve this web application ?

Today i have develop some differents parts : 
I used [this script](http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/), and i create the Upload.php page which gets the post variable and try to Create and image.

The problem i have, is that when i post the data, i only get a blob. I would like to get a base64 stream.

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850970/javascript-blob-object-to-base64

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are specifically looking for a "base 64 stream".  If you are sending the `Blob` to your server via ajax, as far as your server is concerned, it's a file.  Treat it no different than any other upload server-side.  A `Blob` is a `File` without a `name` property.  That's perhaps a bit overly-simplistic, but my point is that, again, this is really nothing more than a file as far as your server knows.

Assuming you are sending a multipart-encoded request, I'd like to point out that most user agents will set the `filename` property of the item's Content-Disposition header in the request to "blob" when the item you are uploading is a `Blob` instead of a file.  It is possible to change this value in *some* browsers via the 3rd argument in [`FormData`'s `append` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FFormData#append%28%29), but I wouldn't rely on this just yet.

Also note that, if you are interested in a library that handles all of this already, I maintain, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) which natively supports uploading images via paste in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this old question: Posting an image from clipboard with chrome is pretty much the same as posting a dropped file - except that the image/blob doesn't have the properties "name" and "lastModified".

```
var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
if (!entry) entry = items[i].getAsFile(); 

if (entry instanceof Blob) /** CHROME pastet Bilder als Blob **/
{
    entry.isFile = true;
    entry.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    entry.name = ""+new Date().getTime()+"."+entry.type.split('/')[1];
}

if (entry.isFile)
{
//handle dropped file
}
```