# How to receive php image data over copy-n-paste javascript with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, image-uploading, onpaste

I try to make an image-upload functionality similar to the one GMail uses. You copy (CTRL-C) an image from your desktop and paste (CTRL-V) it onto the website. 
The image is then uploaded via a XMLHttpRequest to a php-script that handles the incoming file, whereby "handling" means renaming and storing on the server.

I can already fetch the image (and -data), but I am unable to successfully submit and receive the XMLHttpRequest.
My Javascript code looks like that:

```
  document.onpaste = function(e){
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
        if (e.clipboardData.items[1].kind === 'file') {
            // get the blob
            var imageFile = items[1].getAsFile();
            console.log(imageFile);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
                submitFileForm(event.target.result, 'paste');
            };
        }
    };

 function submitFileForm(file, type) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('submission-type', type);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'php/image-upload.php');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log('all done: ');
            } else {
                console.log('Nope');
            }
        };

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

The handling php (`php/image-upload.php`) looks like that:

```
$base64string = $_POST['file'];
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($base64string));
```

I think the `$_POST['file']` stays empty, but I am not sure.
What's more, I also encounter the "blob size" (displayed with console.log()) is way larger than the actual image size. But maybe that's no matter or caused by encodings.

The developer console displays this.

```
{"0":{"type":"text/plain","kind":"string"},"1":{"type":"image/png","kind":"file"},"length":2} image-upload.js:8
Blob {type: "image/png", size: 135619, slice: function}
```

If I view the file-info by right-clicking the actual image file, it shows `5,320 bytes (8 KB on disk)` in size.

I do not necessarily need to use a `XMLHttpRequest`, it was just what came to my mind first. If there's a better way of achieving realtime image-uploading to a server with javascript, please let us know.

Comment: what does the network tab of your developer console shows. is the file being actually submitted over the wire or an empty form is being sent.

Comment: your `reader.onload = function(event) {
             console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
             submitFileForm(event.target.result, 'paste');
         };` function is not firing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> you copy (CTRL-C) an image from your desktop and paste (CTRL-V) it onto the website.

No, that is [impossible](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/#pasting-html-and-multi-part-data). What you can paste is e.g. screenshots and images from the web, that's [what gmail does](http://gmailblog.blogspot.fi/2011/06/pasting-images-into-messages-just-got.html).

Your biggest mistake is using FileReader when you already have a file, the `$_FILES` array is filled when there is a proper HTTP upload not for ad hoc base64 POST param. To do a proper HTTP upload, you just `.append()` a file or blob object (`File`s are `Blob`s).

This is a stand-alone PHP file that should just work, host the file, open it is a page, take a screenshot, then paste it while on the page and after a few seconds the image should appear on the page.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
    header("Content-Type: " . $_FILES['file']['type'] );
    die($file_contents);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
}
print_r($_FILES);
?>

<script>
document.onpaste = function (e) {
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    var files = [];
    for( var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; ++i ) {
        var item = items[i];
        if( item.kind === "file" ) {
            submitFileForm(item.getAsFile(), "paste");
        }
    }

};

function submitFileForm(file, type) {
    var extension = file.type.match(/\/([a-z0-9]+)/i)[1].toLowerCase();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, "image_file");
    formData.append('extension', extension );
    formData.append("mimetype", file.type );
    formData.append('submission-type', type);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open('POST', '<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL)
                .createObjectURL( xhr.response );
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'])['extension']` was empty :(. If you can tell me how I'll be able to get the image extension it's yours. :)

Comment: perfect, i just replace XMLRequest with ajax code, which does not matter, only depend on what you are using.

Answer (score 3):

i have posted a full working example. The problem before was you needed to construct the blob properly. by injecting the file data inside an array notation

```
document.onpaste = function(e){
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
    if (e.clipboardData.items[0].kind === 'file') {
            // get the blob
        var imageFile = items[0].getAsFile();
        console.log(imageFile);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
            submitFileForm(event.target.result, 'paste');
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(imageFile);
    }
};

function submitFileForm(file, type) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var myBlob = new Blob([file], { "type" : "image/png"} );
    formData.append('file', myBlob, 'file.jpg');
    formData.append('submission-type', type);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/task/file');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log('all done: ');
        } else {
            console.log('Nope');
        }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: Right, I send the data now correctly. Yet, a file of zero bytes is created each time. I also tried using $_FILES but I am not sure that's really right. Any idea on that?

Comment: Sounds good, but it did not work for me. The file size stays 0 Bytes. Note, that Blob takes an array as its first parameter. Additionally, this way all my $_POST-variables (e.g. 'submission-type') were cleaned out, meaning they are not defined in the php-script. Have you tried it on your own? I would be really thankful if you could help me on that!

Comment: DevZer0 Bounty started!

Comment: Can you please post the php part? :)

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that the image file size is greater than your 'upload_max_filesize' setting?(usually defaults to 2 meg)

Comment: I doubt it, the image size on disk is 5,320 bytes (8 KB on disk)

Answer (score -1):

I guess the file is in the $_FILE array not in the $_POST since it is a file.
If not, you may convert the image to a string an send the imagestring as GET request.