# How to use xmlhttprequest in Firefox with binary data, f.e. images?

Tags: javascript, firefox, binary, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently looking at

```
function readDataFromURL(fuFullHttpURL, fuCallMeOnLoad) {
    var MyThis = this;
    this.fullHttpURL = fuFullHttpURL;
    this.callMeOnLoad = fuCallMeOnLoad;
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", MyThis.fullHttpURL, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/jpg"});
        MyThis.callMeOnLoad(blob);
    };
    oReq.send();
}
```

But that is only for download. How do I upload with this code?
And when I tried downloading an image with xmlhttprequest in former years there was a size restriction to the download. Is there still a size restriction? 
In former times every browser handeled this size-restriction differently, so I can't test this myself.

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120473/3716796 seems to explain uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData` to send files in XMLHttpRequest like below . Although Chrome & FF support it well, it works only in IE10 or above.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var file = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
  xhr.open("post", "your-url", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  xhr.upload.onload = function(event){
    // handle successful upload
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Ty! So I'm pretty sure I can handle upload an download now in principle. (I have also found http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120473/3716796) - So there is only the question of a size-restriction for downloading which I have read about. (I can only test in Firefox, and I'm not sure if my test is reliable because of some current specific settings here.)

Comment: I have some dynamically created image-tag in the webpage. How could I access the image-data and upload it?

Comment: For more info on downloads limit, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx)

Comment: are you using `canvas` or just `img` ?

Comment: I'm having a canvas actually.

Comment: If you're drawing the image to canvas, then you can use canvas context's `getImageData()` to get `ImageData` object whose `data` property will be the byte array

Comment: I just would like to present the upload to the server as file, so I don't have to decode the imageData on the server. Stackoverflow suggests to move the discussion to chat, but I can'T with 15 reputation. But I'm pretty confident I can post a solution in some hours to conclude it.