# Save image from dynamically generated img tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've used HTML5 capabilities of accessing the camera, so I took a snapshot using canvas object, converted the canvas object to an img element (img tag) using `canevas.doDataURL("image/png")`. 
This is all going well, now my purpose is to save the picture - from that dynamically generated img tag - into some folder or DB.

Any indication on where I might start ? That would be great !

P.S : I've resorted to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) in order to get the dynamically generated img tag that will receive the converted canvas object

Comment: You probably can't get access to your client's local domain to save in a local folder. You can certainly upload it to your server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843115/uploading-canvas-context-as-image-using-ajax-and-php

Comment: Hey, I see, but any chance to find a similar code with java (java-ee) ?

Comment: Untested, but I found this: http://blog.sangupta.com/2012/07/saving-html5-canvas-to-java-server.html

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot ! That's good help, will try it out and let you know. Also, found this thread that's quite interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431281/save-png-canvas-image-to-html5-storage-javascript?rq=1