# Get "print screen" from kineticJS div

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I implemented a diagram tool using kineticJS and now I want to generate a PDF with some images captured from the kineticJS stage.

It looks like this:

[image]

My kineticJS div looks like this:

```
<div id="canvasDrawingArea" style="height: 650px; width: 1150px;">
<div class="kineticjs-content" role="presentation" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 1150px; height: 650px;">
<canvas width="1150" height="650" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1150px; height: 650px; background: transparent;"></canvas>
<canvas width="1150" height="650" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1150px; height: 650px; background: transparent;"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is a image like the one below, I did a print screen in my computer, but I don't know how to achieve this through code:

[image]

I have checked this information

[Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

[Save PNG Canvas Image to HTML5 Storage (JAVASCRIPT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431281/save-png-canvas-image-to-html5-storage-javascript)

but in my case I have two canvas because I have two layers.

How can I do this?
I really need to do this, is this possible (I really hope so)?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the stage as an image: `var stageImage = myStage.toImage();`

If you need to export less than all layers on the stage, you need to flatten all the desired layers into a single canvas.

- Create an in-memory canvas using `document.createElement` and set the new canvas element's size to be the same as the stage.
- All KineticJS layers are actually canvas elements. Draw each layer onto the in-memory canvas. You can get a reference to each layer's canvas with `var layer1Canvas=layer.getCanvas()` and then draw that canvas to the in-memory canvas using `context.drawImage(layer1Canvas,0,0)` [and the same with layer2].

At this point your 2 layers have been flattened onto a single canvas that can be exported using `inMemoryCanvas.toDataURL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your guidance and some other stuff I checked on stackoverflow I was able to achieve what I wanted.